# When restoring a main window, a previously maximised child window is no longer maximised

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say you have an Windows Forms application that has a main window with a child window.

If you maximise the main window and the child window and then minimise the main window, the child window also gets automatically minimised. This is correct and expected.

If you then restore the main window (by clicking on its icon in the task bar), the main window is correctly restored as maximised, but the secondary window is restored as non-maximised.

Is there any way to fix this? (It seems like a WinForms bug, but perhaps it's by design...)

TO REPRODUCE (requires two monitors):

1. Create a new default Windows Forms application. This will create a main form called `Form1`.
2. Select `Project | Add Windows Form...` and click `Add` to add a new form called `Form2`.
3. Change the `Form1` constructor to look like this:

   ```
   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       new Form2().Show(this); // New line of code.
   }
   ```
4. Run the application.
5. Move Form1 to one monitor and Form2 to a different monitor.
6. Maximise Form1 and Form2 by clicking the maximise icon on their title bars.
7. Minimise Form1 by clicking the minimise icon on its title bar. Observe that Form2 also becomes minimised.
8. Restore Form1 by clicking its icon on the taskbar.

ACTUAL RESULT:

Form1 is restored to its maximised state.
Form2 is not restored to its maximised state.

EXPECTED RESULT:

Both forms are restored to their maximised state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further searching I was unable to find any documented solution for this, so I have come up with my own. If you add the following method and field to the child form's implementation, it fixes the issue:

```
protected override void OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnVisibleChanged(e);

    if (!Visible)
    {
        _lastState = WindowState;
    }
    else
    {
        if (_lastState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
}

FormWindowState _lastState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

However, if anyone has a better fix I'd be very interested to hear about it.